# What are the requirements to play Kingdom Hearts on Nintendo Switch?

Tags: nintendo-switch, kingdom-hearts, nintendo-switch-online

The [Kingdom Hearts series will come to Nintendo Switch](https://www.nintendolife.com/news/2021/10/kingdom-hearts-integrum-masterpiece-collection-brings-the-entire-saga-to-switch). It will use cloud technology to make this possible, apparantly [it's not the first game that uses this technology](https://www.nintendolife.com/guides/nintendo-switch-cloud-games-list).

What do I need to have except for a Nintendo Switch and the game to play? Do I need to have an online subscription?

Comment: I removed the question regarding how long cloud gaming would be supported, since that is out of our scope

Comment: Well that would be also very interesting but I will take it as a "nobody knows".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following information is taken from [Nintendo Support](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/53518/%7E/cloud-versions-of-games---faq) general FAQ regarding Cloud-based games:

> What do I need to have except for a Nintendo Switch and the game to play?

Since the games are streamed through the cloud, you will need a consistent and stable connection to an internet source.

> Do I need to have an online subscription?

No, you do not need Nintendo Switch Online services to purchase and play the cloud-based games, but you do need it to access and use any online features.